# Interactive Python in neovim vs. vim

Tags: python, vim, neovim

If I have a python program 
eg.

```
i = input("some input: ")
```

that reads input and I execute this program in nvim with:

:!python %

I get an error

> EOF when reading a line

However, if I do exactly the same in vim, there is no error and the program works.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/5573

Comment: @Chris_Rands this seems to be related. But comments say it was fixed in build NVIM v0.2.0-36-gbd33f11. And I am using build NVIM v0.2.0-113-gcbf2a86. I left a comment there. Good to know though that this is not expected behaviour.

Comment: I got informed that it is actually https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/1496 . which is a feature not a bug...